# Sphinxsearch isn't starting

Tags: sphinx

I am trying to startup **Sphinx Search**, but it doesn't seem to be starting. I am not sure if my config file is incorrect or not, because when I start it no errors are getting displayed. Does this look okay?

```
index stories{
    type         = rt
    path         = /usr/share/sphinxsearch/data/stories
    rt_attr_uint = story_id
    rt_field     = title
    rt_field     = description
}

searchd{
    listen                  = 9312
    listen                  = 9306:mysql41
    log                     = /usr/share/sphinxsearch/log/searchd.log
    query_log               = /usr/share/sphinxsearch/log/query.log
    read_timeout            = 5
    max_children            = 30
    pid_file                = /usr/share/sphinxsearch/log/searchd.pid
    sql_sock                = /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock
    max_matches             = 1000
    seamless_rotate         = 1
    preopen_indexes         = 1
    unlink_old              = 1
    workers                 = threads # for RT to work
    binlog_path             = /usr/share/sphinxsearch/data
}
```

Here is the command I am running:

```
root@largedbapi:/usr/share/sphinxsearch# service sphinxsearch start
sphinxsearch stop/pre-start, process 29399
root@largedbapi:/usr/share/sphinxsearch# pidof sphinxsearch
root@largedbapi:/usr/share/sphinxsearch#
```

Comment: what does `pidof searchd` say? The actual daemon is called searchd. sphinxsearch is just the name of the init script.

Answer (score 1):

Had the same problem on Ubuntu Server. I've checked syslog and found it :-)

```
==> /var/log/syslog <==
Oct 24 14:32:27 precise64 logger: To enable sphinxsearch, edit /etc/default/sphinxsearch and set START=yes
```

After following the above suggestion it finally started to work.

Answer (score 0):

try

> pidof searchd

the sphinxseearch process name is searchd not sphinxsearch